# Installing Kubuntu on a dual boot computer

Tags: installation, dual-boot, grub2, partitioning, kubuntu

I am running Ubuntu Gnome 13.10. The computer is a dual-boot machine, Windows 7 and Ubuntu Gnome.

The / partition has around 10GB free space. /home is on a separate partition.

I want to try Kubuntu. Here are the questions:

1. Can this be done? A triple boot machine booting either Ubuntu Gnome OR Kubuntu OR Windows 7?
2. I will need to repartition the / partition and carve out some empty space (around 6gb would be enough?). Can I do this while booted into Ubuntu Gnome? How?
3. Can both installations share /home partition? In that case, will I need to tell Kubuntu installer to mount /home but not format it, correct?

Comment: You can try Kubuntu by installing the metapackage kubuntu-dektop or a virtual machine, or do you really want to install it on it's own partition?

Comment: @xangua Thanks. In either case, it does not give a 'pure' Kubuntu experience. So, the question.

Answer (score 0):

1. Maybe you can boot Windows 7 and use it's internal tools to create a new partition and then use Wubi (If you are not UEFI) to Install Kubuntu from Win7.
2. It is best to use Gparted live CD to shrink and extend partitions from multiple OSes.
3. I am not sure, but I think you are right.